# How do I fix search after renaming ULR in Alternate Access Mappings?

Tags: search, wss-3.0

I am getting the following error in my logs.

`Content source 'Default' has no start addresses; skipping.`

Things I've done:

- Changed "Default" mapping to the internal AD site, just renaming it
- Rebuilt index (nixed DB Objects, rebuilt search DB)
- Setup the Content DB to use the Search Index on the same server
- fixed Back Connection issue per http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861, though I did not yet reset IIS Admin.  However, the internal URL works from IE fine.
- stsadm -o spsearch -action fullcrawlstart

Then in the log, all I get is:

```
Processing content source 'Administration'.  
Processing content source 'Default'.     
Content source 'Default' has no start addresses; skipping.
```

Comment: The solution in this case was 1) update the URL in Application Configuration cache ...All Users\...\GUID\*.* 2) Disable Loopback Check via registry fix (I'd previously tried listing the URL in BackConnectionHostNames, but taht didn't work in this case)

Answer (score 2):

Is the new URL added as a start address in the content source? SharePoint will not add them by itself when you change a url (nor will it remove them, which, if let go unchecked, leads to a mess of unneeded start addresses in the content source).

Comment: I'm guessing the "start address" is something available in MOSS?  I never found that in WSS.